# Apache Fluent HttpClient behind a proxy results in unknown host

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to use Apache fluent client with a proxy but I'm getting `UnknownHostException` for the target host.
Why httpclient is trying to resolve the host using dns directly instead of using the proxy?

Here's my code so far:

```
String response = Executor.newInstance()
    .auth(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort), "user", "pass")
    .authPreemptiveProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
    .execute(Request.Get("http://example.com")).returnContent().asString();
```

I would need somehow to inform httpclient to use dns resolver that is based on the proxy (or don't use it at all, as all it needs is connecting to the proxy server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting auth credentials is not enough. Try using `Request#viaProxy` to execute the request via a proxy

```
    String response = Executor.newInstance()
            .auth(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort), "user", "pass")
            .authPreemptiveProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
            .execute(Request.Get("http://example.com").viaProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))).returnContent().asString();
```